# Struggling with .get()

Tags: c++, get, iostream

I'm not sure why this issue is arising. I'm coming back to C++ after about a year apart, and I need to get a single character from an input file. From all the documentation I'm reading online, using this .get() method should return the single character, but it doesn't. Instead, every time it gets to the output, it's returning /377 over and over again. I've tried a bunch of different permutations of what I've got below, but it's still not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "INVALID INPUT" << std::endl;
    }

    std::ifstream input;
    input.open(argv[1]);

    char c;

    while (input.get())
    {
        c = char(input.get());
        std::cout << c << ' ';
    }

    input.close();

    return 0;
}
```

And my input file:

```
Queries:
  childOf(x,y)
  parentOf('Dad', 'Mom')
```

I know it's simple, just trying to get a parser working for a class.

Comment: Are you purposefully calling `.get()` twice in each while loop iteration? It is being called once when `while  (input.get())` is evaluated, and then again at `c = char(input.get());` if that evaluates true.

Comment: `while (input.get(c))` and get rid of the invoke inside the loop entirely.

Comment: Perhaps you should check that the file was successfully opened before you check what is read from it?